# How to import data in PostgreSQL from file with .LOD extension?

Tags: database, postgresql, import

I got data file with .LOD extension from which I have to import data in the PostgreSQL database. I never worked with .LOD files. Can someone please help me with commands or steps that I need to follow to import data in my database?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your .LOD file, which application created it, it is a text file similar than a CSV, ....

Comment: The files that I got has text data only from a web application for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text data are well formatted try using the COPY function http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html or you can try http://pgloader.io/ too. If the datas are not well formatted you'll have to write a script to do the load.

Comment: I opened file in np++ and data is like csv file only

Comment: So you'll can import it with COPY